# What could be the CSS Filter Value if I want to apply Green Scale filter effect like the movie The Matrix?

Tags: css, wordpress, filter

I am trying to apply a green filter effect like the movie The Matrix.

I have made the following filter property combinations in CSS, but still not getting the exact thing.

Could anyone please help me?

[Original Image of The Matrix](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fflx-editorial-wordpress%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F03%2F17123153%2FThe-Matrix.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Feditorial.rottentomatoes.com%2Farticle%2Fprepare-to-re-enter-the-matrix-and-more-movie-news%2F&docid=UXMW79ormWoF3M&tbnid=xSi858mgPgKPbM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj91MLm3PvVAhUG-lQKHRYCCMYQMwisAigPMA8..i&w=700&h=380&bih=920&biw=1680&q=the%20matrix&ved=0ahUKEwj91MLm3PvVAhUG-lQKHRYCCMYQMwisAigPMA8&iact=mrc&uact=8): and the 
[Green Filter Image of The Matrix](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2F18675-presscdn.pagely.netdna-cdn.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F06%2Fmatrix.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fbaldmove.com%2Ftag%2Fthe-matrix%2F&docid=3b_KH0TtmtrIlM&tbnid=_0VYwJNvz7f6XM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj91MLm3PvVAhUG-lQKHRYCCMYQMwieAigBMAE..i&w=1280&h=720&bih=920&biw=1680&q=the%20matrix&ved=0ahUKEwj91MLm3PvVAhUG-lQKHRYCCMYQMwieAigBMAE&iact=mrc&uact=8): -

Following is the CSS Code

```css
.class-name img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) brightness(100%) contrast(140%) saturate(80%) hue-rotate(90deg) opacity(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) brightness(100%) contrast(140%) saturate(80%) hue-rotate(90deg) opacity(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
} 

.class-name img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) sepia(0%) brightness(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100%) hue-rotate(0deg) opacity(100%);
    filter: grayscale(0%) sepia(0%) brightness(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100%) hue-rotate(0deg) opacity(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter: hue-rotate(300deg);` to change the color and give the image a similar effect as the matrix one. Hope it helps!

```css
img {
    filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/flx-editorial-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/17123153/The-Matrix.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried on my images, but it is not working as it works on The Matrix image. I guess this is because the original The Matrix image is in blue and that is why, the hue-rotate(300deg) works. My picture is very simple kind of a natural view which consists of multiple color combinations. That is why, I first want to show all colors as one unique color (like in The Matrix it is blue) and then want to apply filter.  Is that possible?

Comment: Can you provide a picture so I can take a look at it?. Or you can also try to change the 300deg to another value.

Comment: HI.. My images are into multiple colors so I could not able to achieve exactly like Matrix effect, but after applying hue-rotate 120 deg, I could able to achieve similar kind of  effect.